# How to get min value of all cities of yesterday?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

How to **get min** value(temp) of all cities of yesterday.
I want:
Indore:min value:yesterday date
Bhopal:min value:yesterday date
Mumbai:min value:yesterday date

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can do:

```
select name, min(temp)
from t
where write_date < current_date and
      write_date >= current_date - interval '1 day'
group by name;
```

You can also write the `where` clause as:

```
where date_trunc('day', write_date) = current_date - interval '1 day'
```

However, using the function `date_trunc()` prevents the use of the index for the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, min(temp) from table 
where date(write_date) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) 
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1/86400
group by name
```

this will do your job

Comment: use 'sysdate-1'

Comment: Where date = 'Today Date() -1' this one

Comment: Still, it gives error..ERROR:  column "sysdate" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rent_weather where date(write_date) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - ...

Comment: Sir, it will work when i use where date(write_date) ='2018-03-29' but want to use today date - 1.

Comment: There is no `sysdate` in Postgres (or standard SQL). You need to use `current_date`